# Invoke JIRA CLI remotely

Tags: jira, jira-cli

I have a requirement to deactivate users using JIRA CLI.

For this I have to invoke the JIRA CLI through a remotely.

Can this be done? Is there any way to invoke?

Comment: What is "a remotely" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just [running a command voer ssh](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux#Running_Commands_Over_SSH), in case it is running on a unix based system.

```
ssh jira.prd.org "jira-cli ..."
```